# ThreadCount Metric in AzureAppService

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-plans

I have an `S2` AppService plan that has a webjob with an instance count of `1` (default).
The webjob basically reads from a service bus topic using `5` (configurable) concurrent threads.

Recently, we had a huge load coming in and the webjob was unable to quickly read through all the messages in the SB Topic, so we increased the instance count from `1 to 10` and the threads from `5 to 10`.

I am trying to understand if the webjob's thread count has any relation with the appservice's threadcount metric?
If yes, I still see the max thread count as `35`.
If no, is there a way to correctly measure the number of active threads of my webjob at any instance of time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the doc [Understand metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understand-metrics): **Thread Count** --> `The number of threads currently active in the app process`. It should include the azure webjob's thread count. But as per my testing, the doc seems incorrect.

You can give it a try by going to the [kudu site](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu#kudu) to check the `thread count` for each webjobs.

Steps: Go to azure portal -> your azure web app -> `Advanced Tools` -> click the `go` button:

[image]

Then in the kudu site -> click the `Process explorer` tab, then check the `thread_count` column for threads of your webjob:

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you for the detailed answer Ivan.